# check/uncehck checkboxlist with jquery

Tags: jquery

most examples i have seen online have a snippet where they use 2 checkboxes, one for just one checkbox (all) and the second is the checkboxlist. In myy case i have only one checkboxlist bound to datasource, example my datasource list options are(All,apple,orange,red,blue), I got most of it working except when everything is unchecked and i check the last item, example blue, it checks the ALL option. so not working properly. id is the id of the 'All' item in the list

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var id = "#<%=cbOptions.ClientID %>_0";
     var checkboxlistid = "#<%= cbOptions.ClientID %>";
     $(id).click(function () {
         $("#<%= cbOptions.ClientID %> input:checkbox").attr('checked', this.checked);
     });
     $(checkboxlistid +  " input:checkbox").click(function () {
         if ($(checkboxlistid).attr('value') != 0) {
             if ($(id).attr('checked') == true && this.checked == false) {
                 $(id).attr('checked', false);
             }
             else {
                 if ($(id).attr('checked') == true && this.checked == true)
                     CheckSelectAll();
             }

         }
     });
     function CheckSelectAll() {
         var flag = true;
         $(checkboxlistid + " input:checkbox").each(function () {
             if ($(checkboxlistid).attr('value') != 0) {
                 if (this.checked == false) {
                     flag = false;
                 }
                 else {
                     if ($(id).attr('checked') == true && this.checked == false) {
                         flag = false;
                     }
                     else {
                         flag = true;
                     }
                 }
             }
         });

         $(id).attr('checked', flag);
     }
      });    
         </script>
                <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="cbOptions" >
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Give some more information about other scripts and markup you have. I created a asp.net v2.0 website and copied all your script and markup and manually added the listItems to the CheckBoxList and the blue only checks blue and only all checks all

Comment: Can you provide the code in pure html/js please?

Comment: There must be `id` conflicting in ur html; and google this `" Check/uncheck all all checkbox via jQuery "` and you will get a lot of results. ALL D BEST

Comment: some of : http://forums.asp.net/p/1444702/3281548.aspx and
http://nice-tutorials.blogspot.com/2010/08/checkuncheck-all-checkboxes-using.html and 
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article894-checkuncheck-all-checkboxes-with-jquery-.aspx

Comment: ok, i edited the code, this is all the content. I did a search and got this from the web and tried to tweak it, I did it with javascript just fine, but the jquery syntax sometime just throw me..I just wanted to be less code, but i ended up with more code than javascript.

Comment: the id's are fine i checked them in view source code, just the logic is funky.

Comment: The problem is not in what you have posted so far. When I check Blue is only checks the blue and not all check boxes. This script is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var id = "#<%=cbOptions.ClientID %>_0";
            var checkboxlistid = "#<%= cbOptions.ClientID %>";
            $(id).click(function () {
                $("#<%= cbOptions.ClientID %> input:checkbox").attr('checked', this.checked);
            });
            $(checkboxlistid + " input:checkbox").click(function () {
            if ($(id).attr('checked') == true && this.checked == false) {
                $(id).attr('checked', false);
            }
            else 
                CheckSelectAll();
            });
            function CheckSelectAll() {
                $(checkboxlistid + " input:checkbox").each(function () {
                    var checkedcount = $(checkboxlistid + " input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
                var checkcondition = $(checkboxlistid + " input[type=checkbox]:").length - 1
                if (checkedcount >= checkcondition)
                    $(id).attr('checked', true);
                else
                    $(id).attr('checked', false);
                });   
            }
        });    
         </script>
                <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="cbOptions" >
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code as your setting checked attribute instead of using true and false use checked and '' respectively..   more over you cannot have same id for all check box.id's are unique.. if your using same id for all checkbox then it won't work at all. if so make it as class name and use `$(.classname)` selector

```
function CheckSelectAll() {
             var flag = "checked";
             $(checkboxlistid + " input:checkbox").each(function () {
                 if ($(checkboxlistid).attr('value') != 0) {
                     if (this.checked == false) {
                         flag = '';
                     }
                     else {
                         if ($(id).attr('checked') == true && this.checked == false) {
                             flag = '';
                         }
                         else {
                             flag = "checked";
                         }
                     }
                 }
             });

             $(id).attr('checked', flag);
         }
          });
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response I tried your function, but it's not working, I was able to get it to work using a count on how many were checked, i will post the compelete answer.